# how come my images aren't showing up so crisp

Tags: html, css, image, png

my header images look watered down. I set the opacity to 60%, so I suspect that's why this is happening, but for some reason it's not happening on the site I'm trying to replicate with the exact same settings.

my site: http://webdev.edulence.com/getchell/

their site: http://getchellcompanies.com

Comment: opacity applies to ALL child elements of whatever you've set the opacity on, so if you set a div to 60%, any images within are also 60%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using opacity, use RGBa - *alpha channel* on the element instead.

See: [http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba](http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/)

Answer (score 1):

Because in yours the image is a child of the opacity: 0.6 and in theirs it is not:

[image]

That's their HTML. The blue line is the div with opacity and the red lines are the div+image. They are siblings.

In your code they are not siblings, instead the red is a child of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because of opacity that you have set to 0.6 on #logo in style.css. The reference site (http://getchellcompanies.com) is also setting the opacity but it is not on the LOGO but on an another DIV that is placed along with the div with #logo ID.

I hope making the same structure will provide you same result.

Answer (score 0):

The difference I see is this. They have

```
<div class="translucentColorBar xACC63F" style="height: 116px;"></div>
```

After the two images which is the same width and height .

```
.translucentColorBar {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.xACC63F {
    background-color: #ACC63F;
}
```